# Help: Wild Rabbit

Tags: rabbits

I brought in a wild eastern cotton tail rabbit 2 days ago and I can't keep it as a pet. I was wondering if I keep it until it grows a little bigger that I can release it back into the wild where I found it? Or would it domesticate by then?

Comment: What's keeping you from releasing it right now? Is it in bad condition?

Comment: i think you have left out a lot of information needed to give you a good answer,is it an addult or a baby rabbit,did you find it right outside your house or is it from a location away from where you live.

Answer (score 2):

If it's healthy, I would take it back to where it came from as soon as reasonably practical.

Domesticating a wild animal as cute as a rabbit is a nice romantic thought, but in reality, you're running the risk of bringing whatever diseases the animal has into close contact with you and other pets.

And if it's an adult, you may not be able to tame it enough to be petted.  If it's a young animal, then it obviously needs its parents.

Comment: From the dupe target it seems that even if it is a young animal, the expectation of domesticating it may be unrealistic.